# How to parse big nested JSON file with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm working on my Web API on Spring and it should enable to provide endpoints and serve the relevant information based on data read from a JSON file. But I have a problem with deserializing nested JSON file with Jackson.

I created a Book class and I tried map JSON to HashMap to keep these Objects.
But JSON file has more data than I want to get, and its nested like 'volumeInfo'.

```
class Book {

    private String isbn;
    private String title;
    private String subtitle;
    private String publisher;
    private long publishedDate;
    private String description;
    private int pageCount;
    private String thumbnailUrl;
    private String language;
    private String previewLink;
    private double averageRating;
    private String[] authors;
    private String[] categories;

// getters and setters
```

data.json file sample

```
{
 "requestedUrl": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=java&maxResults=40",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "books#volume",
   "id": "7tkN1CYzn2cC",
   "etag": "pfjjxSpetIM",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/7tkN1CYzn2cC",
   "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "A Hypervista of the Java Landscape",
    "publisher": "InfoStrategist.com",
    "industryIdentifiers": [
     {
      "type": "ISBN_13",
      "identifier": "9781592432172"
     },
     {
      "type": "ISBN_10",
      "identifier": "1592432174"
     }
    ],

  ]
}
```

How can I get to that volumeInfo with Jackson ?

Comment: So you have a JSON representation of a resource and your class Book. Are you asking "how do I go from the JSON to an list of Book instances"?

Comment: Try Jackson's tree parsing feature (this basically is making use of maps and lists) and extract the data as needed.

Comment: Ok but can I parse only that data, what I declare in class ?

Comment: @M.Matt no: you can't, but you can parse it into a generic structure from which you can then extract the info you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse it as `JsonNode`, iterate over each node in array and convert to `Book`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(json); // read as JsonNode 
JsonNode items = root.at("/items");
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
if (items.isArray()) {
    ArrayNode array = (ArrayNode) items;
    array.forEach(n -> {
        Book book = mapper.convertValue(n.get("volumeInfo"), Book.class); // convert to Book
        books.add(book);
    });
}
System.out.println(books);
```